# Trying to filter out unique post_ids from a CSV

Tags: regex, unix

So I have a multi-column CSV which is basically a Facebook dataset and it has a column which has the post ID's in this format:

> pageid_postid (eg: 943554_3942952 or sometimes _29472_2847847)

I've been tasked to count the unique "postids" in the column as there are multiple posts for a single page. To give you some context, these are some lines of the column:

```
post_id
86680728811_272953252761568
86680728811_273859942672742
86680728811_10150499874478812
86680728811_244555465618151
86680728811_252342804833247
_22228735667216_1015116180247221722
_22228735667216_1015116223698221722
_22228735667216_1015179722271221722
_22228735667216_1015179767034221722
_22228735667216_1015179907764721722
_22228735667216_1015194803861221722
```

As you can see above, there are 2 "pageids" and then several "postids" corresponding to the page and I want to grab the postids (numbers after the underscore).

To achieve this, I whipped up the following command:

```
 cat FB_Dataset.csv  | cut -f2 -d , | grep "/_?[0-9]+_[0-9]+\gm" | wc -l
```

("f2" because the postid's are in the second column)

My regex gives me 0 results found and I think I am not using "grep-friendly" regex. I did try it on an line regex tester and it worked properly. Also I do not know how to tackle this for multiple pageids so any help would be wonderful.

Comment: `grep "/_?[0-9]+_[0-9]+\gm"` has a malformed pattern string,  you must have written it as `grep -oE '_?[0-9]+_[0-9]+'` I believe. `grep` does not support regex literals.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you very much! I did not know this as I am new to this. This worked perfectly!

Comment: Spoke too soon @WiktorStribiżew, I realized now that I am grabbing the entire ID instead of just the postid. How can I ammend that?

Comment: So, what is the expected output? `86680728811` and `22228735667216`?

Comment: If the string is `_22228735667216_1015194803861221722` then output should be `1015194803861221722`.

Comment: So you need to extract the digit chunk at the end of lines? `grep -oE '[0-9]+$'`

Comment: Yes! That does it! I finally used `cat FB_Dataset.csv  | cut -f2 -d , | grep -oE '[0-9]+$' | uniq | wc -l` and I can see it is only grabbing the numbers at the end. I thank you very much for your patience. Please check the command and tell me if its correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` does not support regex literals, `/pattern/gmi` like notation.

In order to *extract* matches, and not just return matching lines, you need to pass the `-o` option that is placed right after `grep`.

Besides, here you want to extract chunks of digits at the end of lines only, so the pattern you need is a `[0-9]+$` POSIX ERE one (add `-E` option to enable it, else, `+` will be treated as a literal `+` symbol). As you need to get unique occurrences only, pipe the `uniq` command:

```
cat FB_Dataset.csv | cut -f2 -d , | grep -oE '[0-9]+$' | uniq
```

Adding `| wc -l` will return the unique match count.